# Aggregate multiple fields with Elasticsearch from a set of tweets to find relations

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, gephi

I have an Elasticsearch index with a collection of tweets. I'd like to plot a network with Gephi from the relations inferred from the tweets, adding edges among people who replied each other or retweeted.

So I need to somehow aggregate these pairs. If each tweet has an author_name field and rt_user_name and rp_user_name fields, how could I get:

```
@bob <-> @alice = 7 tweets

@alice <-> @robert  = 3 tweets

@robert <-> @bob = 1 tweets
```

with an aggregation function?

I am planning to use the ruby gem

Comment: What are `rt_user_name` and `rt_user_name`?

Answer (score 0):

If each individual document (tweet) has needed information, you could use [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) to get for example most frequent pairs of users. But as Elasticsearch doesn't support `JOIN`s across documents a graph database like [Neo4j](http://neo4j.com/) might provide more flexible data model.